# Why And Logical Operator Assign False To 2nd Operand By Default?

Tags: lua

```
print("dog" and "cat")
```

returns cat instead of dog

so why 1st operand is true and 2nd operand is false by default?

what is the logic behind it?

why Its true and false by default instead of false and true

Comment: are you just wondering about lua's true and false values or do you just want to concatenate dog and cat together?

Comment: i wonder why its true and false by default and not false and true ? no i dont want to concatenate.

Comment: What about this result makes you say the first operand is true and the second is false? That conclusion doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: It is what it is. If you want to know why it is what it is, start with exactly what it is, then ask why.  [The conjunction operator `and` returns its first argument if this value is `false` or `nil`; otherwise, `and` returns its second argument.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.5)

Comment: so i ask you why 2nd operand is false?

Comment: `if "cat" then print('"cat" is not false) end` because [all logical operators consider both `false` and `nil` as false and anything else as true.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.5)

Answer (score 0):

The `and` operator evaluates it's first argument, and if *true* returns the second argument. In comparison, `or` evaluates the first argument, and if *false* returns the second argument.